# FileOutputStream не выводит текст в файл

Tags: java, filestream

Есть следующий участок кода:

```
OutputStream outputStream = null;

try {
    outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    assert outputStream != null;
    assert text != null;
    outputStream.write(text.getBytes());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Проблема в том, что после выполнения содержимое файла удаляется, а `text.getBytes()` выводится в консоль.

Как её можно исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для создания объекта класса `FileOutputStream` Вы используете конструктор:

```
FileOutputStream(String name)
```

При использовании данного конструктора данные будут записываться в начало файла, следовательно при записи информации в файл, все, что было в нем раньше – будет удалено.

Для записи данных в конец файла следует использовать конструктор:

```
FileOutputStream(String name, boolean append)
```

с флагом `append` равным `true`.

---

Метод `void write(byte[] b)` класса `FileOutputStream` записывает данные не в сам файл, а в буфер потока (для того чтобы лишний раз не трогать файл на диске и писать бОльшими блоками). Чтобы записать информацию в файл, после вызова метода `write(...)` необходимо либо:

- вызвать метод `flush()`, если Вы далее еще будете работать с потоком,

либо

- вызвать метод `close()`, если далее с этим потоком Вы работать не будете.

---

В приведенном фрагменте кода, на консоль, кроме стек-трейсов, выводиться ничего не может.

Comment: Добавил вызов метода `close()`, в файл действительно теперь записывается то, что нужно, но проблема с выводом в консоль осталась: ![Вывод программы](http://storage1.static.itmages.ru/i/16/1210/h_1481329384_6710340_308f3b3deb.png)

Comment: @Evgeniy, На какой строке происходит вывод на консоль?

Comment: @zeew, Стал искать строку, понял что у меня вызывается метод, в котором присутствует вывод этого массива. Прошу прощения за невнимательность.